# What is the image size limitation for ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: image, swiftui, scrollview

I am trying to create a scrollable image for large images that are 30,000 by 1800 in size. When I add the image to Assets and reference it in ContentView nothing shows. Smaller images (640 x 480) show and are scrollable.

Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var isTapped: Bool = false
    @State var pointTapped: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    @State var draggedSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    @State var previousDragged: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {reader in
            Image("scroll")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .animation(.default)
                .offset(x: self.draggedSize.width, y: 0)
                .scaleEffect(self.scale)
                .scaleEffect(self.isTapped ? 2 : 1, anchor: UnitPoint(x: self.pointTapped.x / reader.frame(in: .global).maxX, y: self.pointTapped.y / reader.frame(in: .global).maxY))
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2)
                    .onEnded({
            self.isTapped = !self.isTapped
        }).simultaneously(with: DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global).onChanged({ (value) in
            self.pointTapped = value.startLocation
            self.draggedSize = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.previousDragged.width, height: value.translation.height + self.previousDragged.height)
//            print(value.startLocation)
        }).onEnded({ (value) in
//            print(value.location)
            let offsetWidth = (reader.frame(in: .global).maxX * self.scale - reader.frame(in: .global).maxX) / 2
            let newDraggedWidth = self.draggedSize.width * self.scale
            if (newDraggedWidth > offsetWidth) {
                self.draggedSize = CGSize(width: offsetWidth / self.scale, height: value.translation.height + self.previousDragged.height)
            } else if (newDraggedWidth < -offsetWidth) {
                self.draggedSize = CGSize(width: -offsetWidth / self.scale, height: value.translation.height + self.previousDragged.height)
            } else {
                self.draggedSize = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.previousDragged.width, height: value.translation.height + self.previousDragged.height)
            }
            self.previousDragged = self.draggedSize
            }))).gesture(MagnificationGesture().onChanged({ (scale) in
            self.scale = scale.magnitude
        }).onEnded({ (scaleFinal) in
            self.scale = scaleFinal.magnitude
        }))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding to the Image:

```
.renderingMode(.original)
```

just before

```
.resizable()
```

Comment: It still comes up blank and with no console errors.

Comment: try removing ".resizable()"

Comment: update. Removing ".resizable()" allows me to display my large image in macos (catalyst). However on my iPhone 10 it crashes. Maybe its just too much for the little thing.

Comment: I can display it fine in Swift, but with SwiftUI, I still get a white screen, with or without .resizable(). Thanks.